# FTDI RS232 EEPROM

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication, ftdi

The cable we bought from the company is working. We bought the same cable, but the cable we bought does not work.

No password security etc.

Orginal Working Cable FT_Prog EEPROM

```
Device: 0 [Loc ID:0x12] 

Word  MSB
0000: 4000 0403 6001 0600 9680 0008 0200 0A98   @...`...........
0008: 20A2 12C2 1A23 0005 030A 0046 0054 0044    ....#.....F.T.D
0010: 0049 0320 0055 0053 0042 002D 0052 0053   .I. .U.S.B.-.R.S
0018: 0032 0033 0032 0020 0043 0061 0062 006C   .2.3.2. .C.a.b.l
0020: 0065 0312 0046 0054 0031 0051 0032 0032   .e...F.T.1.Q.2.2
0028: 0058 0054 0302 0000 1D6A 645C 0000 0000   .X.T.....jd\....
0030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000   ................
0038: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 F043   ...............C
0040: 044E FBB1 0000 0B7F 60B4 0042 0000 0000   .N......`..B....
0048: 0000 0000 0000 0000 4136 5057 574B 4D44   ........A6PWWKMD
0050: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
0058: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
0060: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
0068: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
0070: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
0078: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
```

New Cable. Not Working EEPROM

```
Device: 0 [Loc ID:0x12] 

Word  MSB
0000: 4000 0403 6001 0600 9680 0008 0000 0A98   @...`...........
0008: 20A2 12C2 1A23 0005 030A 0046 0054 0044    ....#.....F.T.D
0010: 0049 0320 0055 0053 0042 002D 0052 0053   .I. .U.S.B.-.R.S
0018: 0032 0033 0032 0020 0043 0061 0062 006C   .2.3.2. .C.a.b.l
0020: 0065 0312 0046 0054 0031 0050 0057 0047   .e...F.T.1.P.W.G
0028: 0035 004F 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000   .5.O............
0030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000   ................
0038: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 6166   ..............af
0040: 0414 FBEB 0000 7BCF E8B2 0042 0000 0000   ......{....B....
0048: 0000 0000 0000 0000 4155 534A 3338 474E   ........AUSJ38GN
0050: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
0058: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
0060: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
0068: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
0070: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
0078: FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF   ................
```

Please help. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Where am I doing wrong?" Perhaps the "wrong" is using a faulty cable? Have you tried other cables? Have you tried the original (previously working) cable again?

Comment: And why are you so sure it's not working? What *exactly* is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? That the contents of the EEPROM differs, is that really the fault of the cable, or have the EEPROM contents been rewritten?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried 5 wires. None of them worked.

EEPROM contents been rewritten? 
Reply: I have no idea. But the eeprom is completely unwritable.

What exactly is the expected behavior?
The program we use scans the ports but does not find the cable we just bought.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.